# CA animation of a UIView inside a UITableView. Like the one on iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-animation

I've been checking this site for many of my questions before but this is the first time I actually have to ask someting, so I hope I can make myself clear enough.

I have an App which is nearly finish. The main functionallity is in up and running. I'm only concern in making the whole App visually appealing. The App is maninly a database wich scientifical relevant data. I want the user to be able to store custom data in the DB and to do that I've created a "contact-like" view where the user can save some data. The view contains a table and inside this table, the cell have UITextFields. After entering the data, when the user presses a button, I want to animate the content of the textField to a cabinet-like icon. Very much like when you purchase something in the iTunes on a iOS device.
I've been able to do that animation in a "static" view (not a UITableView), playing around with starting point, end point and so on is a bit of a pain in the neck, but doable after all.
I'm doing the animation in a not really conventional way, I think, but actually very effecive. On the press of the button I create a UILabel, I set the text as the text of the textField and then I use viewAnimationWithDuration block to animate the label. Inside the block I also use Core Animation to animate the layer of the label over a path. Again, not conventional, but straight forward.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to create the label over the textField since it is in a UITableView. Mainly the problem is to know the position (or frame, or bounds, or position. I'm really confused already) of the textField and hence, the starting position of the path.

The code I'm using is as follows:

-(IBAction)saveCustom:(id)sender{

```
UILabel *imageViewForAnimation = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(l1, l2, l3, l4)];
imageViewForAnimation.text=label.text;
imageViewForAnimation.alpha = 1.0f;
imageViewForAnimation.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
imageViewForAnimation.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
imageViewForAnimation.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

[self.view addSubview:imageViewForAnimation];    




[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{


                     // Set up path movement Core Animation begins
                     CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

                    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(310, 380); // final point
                    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

                     CGPoint rootViewPoint = [imageViewForAnimation convertPoint:imageViewForAnimation.center toView:taula];


                     CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, rootViewPoint.x, rootViewPoint.y);  // initial point
                     CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 100, 100, 100, 100, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
                     pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
                     CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

                     pathAnimation.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
                     pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion=NO;
                     pathAnimation.duration=10.0f;
                     pathAnimation.delegate=self;

                     [imageViewForAnimation.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"savingAnimation"];
                     [imageViewForAnimation release];
                     //Core Animation ends



                     imageViewForAnimation.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.60, 0.60);
                    // imageViewForAnimation.alpha=0.2;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     [imageViewForAnimation removeFromSuperview];
                 } ];
```

}

Any help on how to proceed will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I went to the Apple Tech Talks in Berlin. In the labs they got, I asked an engineer about that. He wondered that the code I showed him didn't work. I emailed to him and he'll be back to me.

The key thing is to transform the coordinates from the table, to the view.

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableView` shows a number of `UITableViewCell`s. If you want to customize the controls displayed in a cell, you can add additional controls to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell`. Depending on how complicated your needs are, you would do this in the `UITableViewDelegate` or by subclassing `UITableViewCell`. Just be aware that adding subviews to `contentView` will likely interfere with the built-on controls (e.g. `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`).

To position your additional controls or animation effects, you can check the `bounds` of the cell's `contentView`. Add your controls as subviews of `contentView`, animate them, and don't forget to remove them when you no longer need them.

Comment: I'll try that when I have a chance this evening. Thanks for the input! However, in my previous tests, what I have observed is that it doesn't really matter where do I locate the view-to-be-animated, what matters is the startinf position of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty conventional animation to me. And yes, effective.

As to a solution, you just need to save some state info when the user requests a save. And draw your animation label on top of the table. Should be no major problems there as long as you have a view available, super view of the table maybe?

Beyond that, how is your UI setup with respect to this table? How is the save custom activated (does the save all data or a specific field, do you have selected cell which you can access to pull the needed origin of your animation data)?

Also, don't forgot to release your `UILabel` after you add it as a subview, you are leaking it in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback rgarding the animation. I asked on Apple's forum whether or not it was a good practice and I got no response. As for the solution you mention, it was already clear to me, the problem is to locate the view-to-be-animated on the screen. Since it's a table view, the location is nothing fixed and I don't know how to do it.